# Error Call to a member function store() on string - images upload error

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to do an image upload on the public function create, but when I click on the button to send the form and do the register this error appears "Error Call to a member function store() on string" - i already tried to include the "enctype=”multipart/form-data”" on the form but didn't work. can somenone help me please?

PUBLIC FUNCTION CREATE

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        
        $user = Auth::user()->id;
        $data = $request->all();

        /*if($request->image->isValid()){*/

           $image = $request->image->store('livros');
           $data['image'] = $image;
     /*   }*/
        Livro::create([
            'users_id' => $user,
            'namel' => $request['namel'],
            'autor' => $request['autor'],
            'editora' => $request['editora'],
            'categoria'=> $request['categoria'],
            'classificação'=>$request['classificação'] ,
            'descricao'=>$request['descricao'],
            'image'=>$request['image'],
        ]);
        return view('livros/cadastro');

        
    }
```

FORM BLADE FILE

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card" >
            <br>
            <div class="textocs">
               <h4>CADASTRO DE LIVROS</h4>

               </div>
<br><br>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" enctype=”multipart/form-data” action="{{ url('/cadastro_livros') }}">
                        @csrf
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="file" class="form-control @error('image') is-invalid @enderror" name="image" value="{{ old('image') }}" >

                                @error('image')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror

                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        

                        <br><br>
                        
                               
                    </form>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Show us your `web.php` please, I am sure you have an error there.

Comment: Route::post('/upload', UploadFoto::class)->name('upload.foto.user');

Answer (score 0):

Change your route to:

```php
Route::post('/upload', 'UploadFoto@store')->name('upload.foto.user');
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution resolved that error, but now appear a new one "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."